# What happens to the bond ETF when the underlying bond matures

Tags: bonds, bond-funds

When a bond matures, what happens to the corresponding bond ETF? It still keeps on going as if nothing has happened. How does this work? I guess there is some kind of rolling over happening here, but how exactly?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

A bond ETF will hold a basket of many, many bonds. As individual bonds mature, the fund reinvests in newer ones. These can be newly issued bonds or existing ones in the secondary market with time till maturity.

Comment: I would add that many bond etfs sell all their bonds well before maturity avoiding this.